# If we attach session to HTTP then it becomes stateful?

Tags: apache, http, session

I have been reading that HTTP is stateless. If we attach session to HTTP then it becomes stateful?. What is the difference between HTTP with session  and TCP

Comment: HTTP has no sessions, but those are usually implemented in the next underlying layer (e.g. Java, PHP, Python). HTTP itself is and remains stateless, but to know in an application, which user we got here, we need some kind of workaround to this default behavior, which we call sessions.

Comment: Thank you. Is session object  created when the user logs in into the browser? what happens when same user tries to login using different brower/computer?

Comment: This depends on the session handling that is used. Usually a session is only valid for one browser session.